# React - is it bad practice to pass up a callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a REACT app which is basically a till for adding items to an order. I have my `OrderSection` which does most of the grunt work, including having a barcode scanner, and I have my `Search` component which is a child of OrderSection, and if someone clicks on a search result it passes that back up to OrderSection via a prop callback.

Now, this is what I initially had, but it had problems:

```
@autobind
class OrderSection extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            orderItems: [],
            multiMatch: [],
        };
    }

    async barcodeScanner(barcode) {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await serverApi.getItemsFromBarcode(barcode);
        } catch(e) {
            return toast.error(e.message || e.toString());
        }

        let {items} = response;

        if (items.length === 0) {
            toast.info('no matching items found');
        } else if (items.length === 1) {
            this.addItem(items[0]);
        } else {
            // show results in the 'search' section
            this.setState({multiMatch: items})
        }
    }

    addItem(item) {
        // doesn't really matter what happens here
    }

    async lookupAdd(no, code) {
        try {
            let {items} = await serverApi.getItems(no, code);
            let item = items[0];
            if (item) {
                this.addItem(item);
            } else {
            }
        } catch(e) {
            toast.error(e.toString());
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                // render items up here

                <Search  
                    onItemClick={this.lookupAdd} 
                    results={this.state.multiMatch} />
            </section>
        )
    }
}



@autobind
class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchResults: [],
            show: false // change to true to show the search
        }
    }

    // code for updating search results on form submit
    // updating this.state.searchResults

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                // form with search text input here
                // render searchResults here
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (props.results.length) {
            this.setState({searchResults: props.results, show: true});
        }
    }
}

Search.propTypes = {
    onItemClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    results: PropTypes.array
};
```

The main issue here is how in OrderSection, in barcodeScanner, when I have multiple matches, I pass them down as a prop into Search, and then Search sees that prop and updates itself in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function.

I wasn't entirely happy with what was happening there -- it was actually fine most of the time, but there was some annoying unexpected behaviour of Search showing itself when the prop actually hadn't changed.

So I came up with the idea of passing a callback up from Search to OrderSection:

```
@autobind
class OrderSection extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            orderItems: []
        };
    }

    async barcodeScanner(barcode) {
        let response;
        try {
            response = await serverApi.getItemsFromBarcode(barcode);
        } catch(e) {
            return toast.error(e.message || e.toString());
        }

        let {items} = response;

        if (items.length === 0) {
            toast.info('no matching items found');
        } else if (items.length === 1) {
            this.addItem(items[0]);
        } else {
            // show results in the 'search' section
            this.sendMultiMatchToSearch(items);
        }
    }

    setSearchResultsFunc(func) {
        this.sendMultiMatchToSearch = func;
    }

    addItem(item) {
        // doesn't really matter what happens here
    }

    async lookupAdd(no, code) {
        try {
            let {items} = await serverApi.getItems(no, code);
            let item = items[0];
            if (item) {
                this.addItem(item);
            } else {
            }
        } catch(e) {
            toast.error(e.toString());
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                // render items up here

                <Search
                    onItemClick={this.lookupAdd}
                    manuallySetResultsFunc={this.setSearchResultsFunc}
                     />
            </section>
        )
    }
}



@autobind
class Search extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            searchResults: [],
            show: false // change to true to show the search
        };

        if (typeof this.props.manuallySetResultsFunc === "function") {
            const func = (results) => {
                this.setState({searchResults: results, show: true});
                this.flash();
            };
            this.props.manuallySetResultsFunc(func);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                // render searchResults here
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

Search.propTypes = {
    onItemClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    manuallySetResultsFunc: PropTypes.func
};
```

But I feel like this is probably bad react practice. It's producing the behavior I want but I think if a React expert looks at this they wouldn't like it.

Can I get some advice on the proper way to pass search results down to Search to trigger it, while still otherwise allowing the SEARCH element to control its own `searchResults` code

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `<Search>` should only be `show`ing when there are results?

Comment: There are other conditions for search to show, and it manages it's own state of showing, BUT in the case of being forced to show from the parent, when the parent has a multi-match, it's only triggered to show in that context when the multi-match has results.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that you shouldn't have to 'intervene' in this way to modify how your state is updated. You should just set up your state and props and then things should take care of themselves.

Here are some straightforward approaches that I'd typically use:

1) From the OrderSection parent to conditionally render your Search only when there are items:

```
render() {
        return (
            <section>
                {this.state.multiMatch && <Search
                    onItemClick={this.lookupAdd}
                    manuallySetResultsFunc={this.setSearchResultsFunc}
                     />}
            </section>
        )
    }
```

2) Within the `<Search>` child:

```
render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.state.searchResults && this.state.searchResults.map(result=> // map to SearchResults)}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

3) From the OrderSection parent pass in 'isShowing' as a prop:

```
render() {
        const isShowing = !!this.state.multiMatch; // add other logic here if necessary
        return (
            <section>
                 <Search
                    onItemClick={this.lookupAdd}
                    isShowing={isShowing}
                     />
            </section>
        )
    }
```

Then in your Search, extract `isShowing` from props.

The idea is that you only need to update the state and the rendering should take care of itself.

Comment: I may have communicated my situation poorly. There are other conditions in which the Search should show, which is why it manages it's own `show` state. The problem is that it's sometimes running the code in `componentWillReceiveProps` when the `multiMatch` hasn't actually changed. Which is why I started looking for other alternatives.

Comment: Eg I scan a barcode with a multimatch, it shows search correctly, and then I close the search, BUT because multimatch state is still populated in OrderSection, if multimatch doesn't get cleared from the state, other things trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` in the Search despite me not wanting to open search with the multimatch again.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` can get called when nothing changes, which is one of the reasons this approach is problematic

Comment: So how do you recommend I send multimatch down and trigger Search to show?

Comment: have added a 3rd example - does that help?

Comment: mmmm no not really, it is important that the Search is allowed to manage it's own 'showing' state because there are more conditions for it to show than just if MultiMatch from orderSection comes up.

Comment: It sounds like you need to split out that 'showing' logic. Maybe if you posted a fuller example (or a sandbox) it would be easier to see what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce additional props to `Search` component `showMultiMatch` and `onSearchClose` and add `showSearch` to `OrderSection` component(which is set to true when you receive `multiMatch` and set to false in the `onSearchClose` handler). Remove `componentWillReceiveProps` and check condition `this.props.showMultiMatch || this.state.show` in the render function to render search conditionally.